# htaccess file help needed for rewriting url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need help from experts to solve my problem. I'm just starting to learn rewriterule, rbase, and rcond. I want to rewrite my site link like codeigniter MVC. For example:

```
http://localhost/app/index.php?page=profile&user=john -> http://localhost/app/index/page/profile/user/john
```

How to do that? I tried to change for many times, but i don't get url like that but error occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^index/page/(.*)/user/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1&user=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Oh ya... What is [NC], [R], and [L]?

Comment: it say [L] for last rule. If I add more rules, so i only add [L] sign in the last right?

Comment: that will depend how would you like to use it. rules succeeding the rule with L flag that matched won't be processed.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: Oh..Ya.. I forgot to ask about file location. Is it can make conflict with some files. I mean like this: images.jpg inside images folder (http://localhost/app/images/images.jpg). If i rewrite the url like that, the images location will be automatically at: (http://localhost/app/index/page/home/user/john/images/images.jpg). How to fix that?